# Internal exception while debugging custom classes in STS

Tags: eclipse, debugging, spring-tool-suite

I can't see the variables in the the variables tab in the debug mode in STS no matter the configuration settings. The only hint that STS is giving is the following message in the variable tab

`com.sun.jdi.internalexception got error code in reply 35 occurred retrieving 'this' from stack frame`

Also, this is only happening in my custom classes, if I place a breakpoint in any other library class variables are shown as expected. What could this be?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you run into [Eclipse bug 531706](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=531706) which was fixed in Eclipse Photon (4.8). The current release is Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10). Please upgrade.

Comment: I am aware of the bug, I have already upgraded to the latest version and the problem remains.

Comment: Which version exactly does the `org.eclipse.jdt.debug` plug-in have (_Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_, tab _Plug-ins_)? Also which JRE/JDK is used exactly here is of importance here, because the error code 35 message comes from the JRE/JDK and is not from Eclipse.

Comment: You were right, I thought that by doing the updates I would be on the latest version but I was still on 4.8, once I upgraded to 4.10 the problem was solved.

Comment: I think I marked the answer as correct too fast, no offence. But now in the variables tab, instead of the variables I see a list of the methods of the class which has breakpoints, something like the Outline in the Spring mode. Have you ever encountered something like that?

Comment: @ChristosK. Could you please show a screenshot of that?

Comment: @ChristosK. I don't see any methods on the screenshot but only variables (and references) with (for non-primitive types) their fields (which also have fields if the value is not `null` and a non-primitive type).

Comment: Ok, so far I do not disagree, but I used to be able to see instances of my objects and the values of their fields.

Comment: The _Variables_ view shows the variables of the object instance of the in the _Debug_ view selected stack trace item.